# Import other files of module from module base

Tags: python, module

I'm currently writing a Python module.

Please take a look at the following module structure:

```
gjms
├── data.db
├── event
├── games
│   └── game
├── __init__.py
├── user
│   └── __init__.py
└── util
    ├── database.py
    ├── email.py
    └── password.py
```

Is it possible to set my Python path in a way, so that for I can always import from the module base? **As an example:** I want to import the database.py file from the util module in the user module like so:

```
import gjms.util.database
```

It would be preferable to be able to do this from any place in the module.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *parent* directory of `gjms` is listed in `sys.path` and you have a `__init__.py` file in `gjms` then your import will work from anywhere in your project.

In other words, `gjms` must be a package, making it importable.

Comment: That was surprisingly easy. Thanks a bunch!